# how to use custom operation to get content from another class

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

This question is a follow up to [how to link http client with ApiResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659438/how-to-link-http-client-with-apiresource?noredirect=1#comment119594746_67659438So) I have client which retrieves xml data and it converts it in to associative array:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Entity\GLAccountBalance;
use SimpleXMLElement;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class GetYukiAccountingBalance implements GetYukiAccountingBalanceInterface
{

   /**
     * @var HttpClientInterface
     */
    public static $balance;
    public static $succesfulResponse;
    public static $succesfulResponseTest;
    public static $data;

    private $httpClient;

    private const YUKI_API_URL = 'https://api.yukiworks.nl/ws/Accounting.asmx/GLAccountBalance';
    private const YUKI_API_HOST = 'https://api.yukiworks.nl';
    private $yukiApiKey;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, SerializerInterface $serializer, $yukiApiKey)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->yukiApiKey = $yukiApiKey;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function GLAccountBalance($administrationID, $sessionID, $transactionDate)
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', self::YUKI_API_URL, [
            'query'   => [
                'administrationID' => $administrationID,
                'sessionID' => $sessionID,
                'transactionDate' => $transactionDate
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'yukiapi-host' => self::YUKI_API_HOST,
                'api-key'  => $this->yukiApiKey
            ]
        ]);
        
                
    

        $data = [];
        $balance = GetYukiAccountingBalance::$balance;
        $balance = new SimpleXMLElement($response->getContent());
        
        
        foreach ($balance->GLAccount as $account) {
            $data[] = [
               'accountBalanceCode' => (string)$account->attributes()->Code ?? '',
               'accountBalanceType' => (string)$account->attributes()->BalanceType ?? '',
               'accountBalanceDescription' => (string)($account->Description ?? ''),
               'accountBalanceAmount' => (string)($account->Amount ?? '')
            ];

        }
        
        $succesfulResponse = GetYukiAccountingBalance::$succesfulResponse;

        $succesfulResponse = [
        'content' => $data
    ];

    return $succesfulResponse;
  
    }
}
```

I then have created a custom operator which returns the same data but it can now be used by api-platform annotations as you will see later. I have used the documenation in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/ :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ContextAwareCollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\GLAccountBalance;
use App\Http\GetYukiAccountingBalance;
use App\MethodParameters;
use SimpleXMLElement;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class GetGLAccountBalanceController 

{
    
    private $getBalanceClient;

    public function __construct(GetYukiAccountingBalance $getBalanceClient)
    {
        $this->getBalanceClient = $getBalanceClient;
    }

    public function __invoke(GLAccountBalance $data): GLAccountBalance
    {
        $methodParameters = new MethodParameters();
        $administrationID = $methodParameters->administrationID;
        $sessionID = $methodParameters->sessionID;
        $transactionDate = $methodParameters->transactionDate;
        $glAccountBalance = $this->getBalanceClient->GLAccountBalance($administrationID, $sessionID, $transactionDate);
        // Do something
        $data = $glAccountBalance['content'];
        return $data;
    }
    
}
```

Finally i have entity where the ApiResource() is described:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\GLAccountBalanceRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  shortName="glbalance", 
 *  collectionOperations ={
        "GET" ={
            "openapi_context"={
                "summary"= "Retieves a balance based on transactionDate",
                "parameters"= {
 *                      {
 *                          "name"="transactionDate",
 *                          "description"="List of great ledger balancey from third party accounting program",
 *                          "default"="15000",
 *                          "in"="path",
 *                          "required"=true,
 *                          "type"="string"
 *                      }
 *                  },


            },
            "method" = "GET",
            "path" = "/balanceList/{transactionDate}/glaccountbalance",
            "controller" = GetGLAccountBalanceController::class,
        }

    },
   )

 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=GLAccountBalanceRepository::class)
 */
class GLAccountBalance
{
   
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true,)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceDescription;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceAmount;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceCode;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="glAccountBalance", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceDescription;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceDescription(?string $accountBalanceDescription): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceDescription = $accountBalanceDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceAmount;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceAmount(?float $accountBalanceAmount): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceAmount = $accountBalanceAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceCode;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceCode(?string $accountBalanceCode): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceCode = $accountBalanceCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceType;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceType(?string $accountBalanceType): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceType = $accountBalanceType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->addGlAccountBalance($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            $user->removeGlAccountBalance($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see i want to get GLAccountBalance result from the class with the same name using the transactionDate '04-26-2021' because this record with the that transactionDate exists from the third party api that i make a call to with the client.

I am really confused how i am able to connect everything so it will work, because i have no clue what i am supposed to do now.

Comment: Easiest way is to implement [ItemDataProvider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-item-data-provider) for your `GLAccountBalance` resource. You do not need to resolve it to Doctrine entity at all, you can simply call 3rd party api from your data provider. The problem is you have marked entity as Doctrine entity thus api-platform is using it's internal doctrine providers to feed the data to the resource. if you wish to fetch and hydrate single property, you can decorate doctrine provider / add it at normalization / with DTO pattern and add your custom data to the response

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379585/api-platform-returning-data-from-external-api